# Specific stylesheet for IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

How can I make a specific CSS stylesheet for Internet Explorer 8?

I mean, how can I load it only if the browser is IE8? (And not IE7 and IE6)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link href="/stylesheets/iestyle8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link href="ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: +1 for bothering to at least give the OP a link to more information (although just linking, rather than just a bit of text, isn't great form).

Comment: @Patrick: If you really want **just** IE8, the above is fine. If you want IE8 *and later* (e.g., because you're using something new that will be continued in IE9, which isn't that far away), use `if gte IE 8` instead -- the difference is the `gte`, which is (of course) "greater than or equal".

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```