# Why this function not work on ie 7 ,8 (delay and fadein)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Why this function not work on ie 7 ,8 (delay and fadein) ?

on other browser are delay and fadein good.

But on ie all element show in same time (not delay and fadein).

http://jsfiddle.net/7u8qmdoo/2/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    var i = 0;
    (function fadeInNext()
    {        
        $("#num" + i).fadeTo(1000,1);
        console.log("Fading in " + i);
        i++;
        if (i < 8)
        {
            setTimeout(fadeInNext, 2000);
        }
    })();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Works fine on IE10. What version is causing you problems?

Comment: Take out `console.log()`

Comment: IE7 and 8 don't support `opacity` so `opacity: 0` is ignored.  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Comment: @ James Montagne --- and ie 7 8 not delay tooo

Comment: Update tested on IE7 emulation. Works fine now.

Comment: @nomwerygeqoilu It is delayed but that is irrelevant because the opacity is never applied so that fade does nothing.  Open your console, you will see the debug statements are properly delayed.

Comment: @DanFromGermany You have no idea how happy I am that my employer is forcing an upgrade to IE11 soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this simpler using `delay` in a basic `for` loop, but you also need to use `fadeIn` instead of `fadeTo` as the opacity animation of `fadeTo` is not handled by IE7:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7u8qmdoo/6/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        $("#num" + i).delay(i * 2000).fadeIn(1000);
    }
});
```

This is the same as:

```
$("#num0").delay(0).fadeIn(1000,1);
$("#num1").delay(2000).fadeIn(1000,1);
$("#num2").delay(4000).fadeIn(1000,1);
```

etc

Comment: Its the fading that is causing you grief in IE7... I will try find a better option for you.

Comment: The update works for me in IE9/IE7 mode but just appears with no fade in IE9/IE8 mode.  Gotta love IE.

Comment: @James Montagne: Gotta *something* IE. Appears to fade correctly in all but IE8 now :(

Comment: It looks like the issue is with IE8 dealing with fading inline elements.  [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114516/does-jquerys-fadein-and-fadeout-not-work-with-ie-8).  Setting them to `inline-block` fixes it, but of course then they're not hidden.  I tried setting them `inline-block` and then hiding them in the js.  That worked, but is pretty ugly.